# Access to Midosuji line platforms with luggage

Tags: trains, accessibility, osaka

I need to travel between Shin-Osaka and Tennoji stations in Osaka. Hyperdia recommends the Midosuji subway line but should I prefer overground lines if I have large luggage? Are there elevators to platforms in these stations or only escalators? This will be outside the rush hour.

The other options are Haruka and Kuroshio trains which I assume are easier to access.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Osaka City Transport Station Guide](http://www.kotsu.city.osaka.lg.jp/station-guide/) to the rescue!  Japanese only, but the station diagrams and their elevator icons are pretty self-explanatory.  In both cases the red lines represent the Midosuji Line.  Click on the 駅構内図を膨大 button in the top right corner to view expanded PDFs.

[Shin-Osaka](http://www.kotsu.city.osaka.lg.jp/station-guide/M/m13/): has elevators both to platform and street level

[Tennoji](http://www.kotsu.city.osaka.lg.jp/station-guide/M/m23/): also has elevators both to platform and street level (see [PDF](http://www.kotsu.city.osaka.lg.jp/library/station-guide/M/m23/pdf/station.pdf) for a more legible version)

That said, if you can time it right the Haruka or Kuroshio will be faster and more comfortable (it's a single stop), but it also costs a lot more (¥870 in an unreserved seat, vs ¥220 for the subway) and runs less frequently.

Comment: Thank you for the links! I found another site that displays the JR-tracks layout of Shin-Osaka station: https://www.westjr.co.jp/global/en/travel-information/routemap/pdf/station_shin-osaka.pdf , these maps combine at the side